# Will android install referrer receiver also listen to broadcasts of other apps installed with a referrer?

Tags: android, install-referrer

I have a Install referrer receiver in my manifest.

```
    <receiver
        android:name="xx.yy.zz.InstallReferrerReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And I get the referrer in the broadcast receiver as:

```
        String referrer = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");
```

My doubt is would the receiver also listen to broadcasts of other apps which are installed with a referrer.
I want to listen to broadcasts for my app only. 
If this problem exists, what would be the solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<receiver
    android:name="xx.yy.zz.InstallReferrerReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        **<data android:scheme="package" />**
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

add your package in the receiver and while receive the broadcast in the OnReceive method check for your package

this will solve your problem